# PDO extensions are not loaded when using httpd, but are shown when using built-in server

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to load sqlite3 pdo driver for use with httpd and php 7.4.2 . 
In my php.ini I set up an absolute path to extensions directory:

```
extension_dir = "D:/MyWebServer/php7_4_2Win32vc15x64/ext"
```

I also enable all sqlite-related pdo extensions in php.ini:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

httpd and built-in php server both can find my php.ini:
[image: php.ini was found and loaded]

But, when using built-in php server I get such result:

[image: sqlite was found and ready to be used]

But when I use httpd I get that PDO extensions were not loaded:

[image: sqlite not found with httpd]

All other extensions work fine with httpd.

How do I make PDO extensions work with httpd?

Comment: Check `extension=pdo_mysql` in php,ini is uncommented

Comment: I don't use mysql, only sqlite. I have pdo_mysql it and it loaded fine, but sqlite extension does not load